# Date calculation within If-then Statement

Tags: datetime, ms-access, date-arithmetic

I need to calculate the number of days between two date fields based on whether one of the dates is null or not.  If the date variable is null I need to incorporate today's date.  Please help.  SAS user trying to set up query for other users in Access 2010 database.  I'm looking for SQL language to insert in my query.  Thanks much!

ex.

```
if dbo.nameoftable[date1] <> " " then time = [date1] - [date2]
elseif dbo.nameoftable[date1] = " " then time = ?todays date - [date2]endif;
```

Thank you!!

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for.  You haven't tagged a language, and though you said "please help with SQL" this doesn't look like SQL.  Or if it is, it's not clear what flavor of SQL you are working with.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back here and edit your question so we can help you.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Matt,  I apologize for any confusion.  I am a proficient SAS user who has been asked to create a query for others to use in Access.  I am asking  for help with language to create an if-then statement in Access.  When I'm in access I see you can look at the underlying SQL language.    I am using Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need if-then logic.  Simply use the [`Nz`](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Nz-Function-8EF85549-CC9C-438B-860A-7FD9F4C69B6C) function, which lets you specify a value to use when the field is null.

Also, you should use [`DateDiff`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f) rather than `-` to be explicit about what units you are working with.

For the current date, use the [`Date`](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Date-Function-DD7A1F27-D957-4969-AB35-01E0BFBFED76) function.  Note that this returns the current day in the *local* time zone of the computer where the query is being executed.

Putting it all together:

```sql
SELECT DateDiff('d', [date2], Nz([date1], Date())) AS [DifferenceInDays] FROM nameoftable;
```